# Magento SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL

Tags: mysql, magento

I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query
>   was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `catalogrule` AS `main_table` WHERE
>   (`is_active` = '1')

I am not able to add products it is very slow, getting down website?

How can I fix this?

Comment: [General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/geting-fatal-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-a)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `/etc/my.cnf` as

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
wait_timeout = 1800 
connect_timeout = 120
```

Comment: I have a shared hosting, I have php.ini and .htaccess

Comment: @DanOproiu:- Try to execute `set global max_allowed_packet=104857600` before your query and then try.

Comment: #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Then you contact your hosting provider and see if they will make changes. Otherwise this is the usual downside to using Magento on Shared Hosting. Magento requires resources to run properly, Shared Hosting wants to share those resources to split them up fairly between ALL the accounts on the server. If the server's over-provisioned, Magento goes bye-bye in an attempt to be fair to all the other users.